# Getting a Docker postgres container to use hosts database files

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a Postgres database running on my host. The datafiles for the database is stored at `/usr/local/var/postgresql@13`.

To get the full system running easily I'd like to have a Docker with a Postgres service running for other Docker apps to connect to. I would however like to have the Docker Postgres service to use the existing datafiles on the host ...

- How do I set up the volume correctly to point to the hosts database files?
- Do have to have a user/password when running the Docker against existing datafiles?

I have the following but can get the volume to work ...

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8081:3011
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - PGHOST=db
      - PGDATABASE=loggingtestdb
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - /usr/local/var/postgresql@13 <--- Need help here.
```

How do I map the container pg datafile location to the hosts pg datafile location?

**Update 1**

This is the datafile folder for the db on the host

[image]

After comments I updated the volumes to below

```
volumes:
  - /usr/local/var/postgresql@13:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

But when running `docker compose` I only get

```
Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /usr/local/var/postgresql@13
```

**Update 2**

`/use/local` works fine. But as soon as I add the  `/var` folder to the path Docker for some reason can’t find it … What am I missing here?

Comment: What is ./pgdata? The location inside docker? Inside the work directory?

Comment: I'll remove that. Just something I tested with ...

Comment: "but can get the volume to work" - can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: After backing up your host's data, try (under volumes) `- "/usr/local/var/postgresql@13":/var/lib/postgresql/data`, this should mount the folder into the docker container. I'd also set the `PGUSER` etc. to the identical values as on your host db. If that works, try experimenting with a different user or password.

Comment: @Taxel thanks! Still couldn't really get it to work ... Updated my question

Comment: Seems like it’s the `/var` folder that for some reason causes an issue. When removing that Docker finds the path. And idea why that is? Running `realpath` doesn’t show anything weird either … Help 